# What are the eigenvalues of this problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

I have the following problem that has been giving me a lot of trouble:

> $$y''-3y'+3(1+\lambda)y=0$$ $$y'(0)=y'(1)=0$$

I know how to solve this type of eigenvalue problems. I try $y=e^{rx}$ and the characteristic polynomial gives me: $r^2 -3r+3(1+\lambda)=0$, so that $$r=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{9-12(1+\lambda)}}2$$, so that the cases I have to study are:

1. $\lambda=\frac{-1}4$
2. $\lambda<\frac{-1}4$
3. $\lambda>\frac{-1}4$

I go on to solve this and obtain my eigenvalues, but my answer is completely different from the book's numerical solution, in which they have found the eigenvalue $\lambda_0=-1$. My question is, how can this be? How do they get to this case? I just need to know this, because I have spent a lot of time on this problem and it is getting me nowhere.

**Edit: I have figured out what I was missing in my solution. Thanks for all your help!**

Comment: This is not a Sturm-Liouville eigenvalue problem nor a PDE. That's just standard ODE with a solution for every value of $\lambda$. What exactly is the question from your book?

Comment: Sorry about that, I am solving S-L problems and it slipped by. The question is to find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of the ODE.

Comment: Everything that you’ve done so far looks good to me. However, the initial conditions that you’ve given only allow for the trivial solution to the equation regardless of the value of $\lambda$. Are you sure that you’ve transcribed the problem correctly?

Comment: Yes, I have just double checked. As I mentioned in another comment, I get solutions for cases 2 and 3.

Comment: *General* solutions exist for all three cases, but when you try to satisfy the initial conditions from above, you’ll find that they force both constants of integration to be zero in all cases. Try it with the complex-eigenvalue solution that you have in your comment to Taamer’s answer, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct - the general form of the differential equation is
$y=e^{rx}$, and when $\lambda\le-1/4$, you get the solution for r.

Now, you still have to solve

> $y'(0)=y'(1)=0$

and this will give you more information about r / about $\lambda$.

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: Thank you. I have tried doing this, and I get a solution for $\lambda<\frac{-1}4$ and $\lambda>\frac{-1}4$, but not for $\lambda=\frac{-1}4$. Is this correct?

Comment: When $\lambda>-1/4$, the second degree equation has no roots in R, has it?

Comment: Well, no, but I just write the solution using Euler's formula for complex numbers: $y=e^{(\frac32+ir_1)x}+e^{(\frac32+ir_2)x}$ so by a linear combination, $y=e^{\frac32x}(c_1cos(rx)+c_2sin(rx))$ , where $r=\sqrt{-9+12(1+\lambda)}$